# How to add graphics to map at lowest level?

Tags: arcobjects, layers, .net, graphics

I am able to create graphics and add them to the map, but they are getting added as the top-most layer.

The labels (if active) of another layer get hidden due to this. I want to know how to add graphics as the lowest layer in the active map.

EDIT 1: Here is the code which I am using to add graphics to the map

```vb
    Dim graphicsContainer As IGraphicsContainer
    graphicsContainer = GetRunningApplication(My.ArcMap.Application.Document.Title).FocusMap
    Dim elem As IElement
    Dim rgbcolor As IRgbColor
    Dim outlineRGBColor As IRgbColor

    elem = Nothing
    rgbcolor = New RgbColor

    If (g.GeometryType) = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPoint Then
        ' Marker symbols
        Dim simpleMarkerSymbol As ISimpleMarkerSymbol
        simpleMarkerSymbol = New SimpleMarkerSymbol

        'set COlors
        rgbcolor.Blue = 255
        rgbcolor.Red = 0
        rgbcolor.Green = 0

        simpleMarkerSymbol.Color = rgbcolor
        simpleMarkerSymbol.Outline = True
        simpleMarkerSymbol.OutlineColor = rgbcolor 'outlineRGBColor
        If SymbolSize = 0 Then
            simpleMarkerSymbol.Size = 8
        Else
            simpleMarkerSymbol.Size = SymbolSize
        End If
        simpleMarkerSymbol.Style = esriSimpleMarkerStyle.esriSMSCircle

        Dim markerElement As IMarkerElement
        markerElement = New MarkerElement
        markerElement.Symbol = simpleMarkerSymbol
        elem = markerElement
    End If

    If g.GeometryType = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolyline Or g.GeometryType = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryLine Then
        '  Line elements
        Dim simpleLineSymbol As ISimpleLineSymbol
        simpleLineSymbol = New SimpleLineSymbol

        'set COlors
        rgbcolor.Blue = 0
        rgbcolor.Red = 255
        rgbcolor.Green = 0
        simpleLineSymbol.Color = rgbcolor
        simpleLineSymbol.Style = esriSimpleLineStyle.esriSLSSolid
        If SymbolSize <> 0 Then
            simpleLineSymbol.Width = SymbolSize
        Else
            simpleLineSymbol.Width = 2
        End If

        Dim le As ILineElement
        le = New LineElement
        le.Symbol = simpleLineSymbol
        elem = le  ' Explicit Cast
    End If

    If (g.GeometryType) = esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPolygon Then
        ' Polygon elements
        Dim simpleFillSymbol As ISimpleFillSymbol
        simpleFillSymbol = New SimpleFillSymbol

        'set COlors
        rgbcolor.Blue = 0
        rgbcolor.Red = 0
        rgbcolor.Green = 255
        simpleFillSymbol.Color = rgbcolor
        simpleFillSymbol.Style = esriSimpleFillStyle.esriSFSForwardDiagonal
        Dim fillShapeElement As IFillShapeElement
        fillShapeElement = New PolygonElement
        fillShapeElement.Symbol = simpleFillSymbol
        elem = fillShapeElement
    End If
```

Comment: You've tagged this as an ArcObjects question, what is your code so far?

Comment: Graphics typically override automatic labels or affect their placement, regardless of draw order. You may need to explore label weights/rankings.

Comment: @Hornbydd I am able to add graphics on map based on geometry (Point, Line, Polygon). The graphics are visible on map as well, its just adding them at lowest level that i am not able to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say *"...add graphics as the lowest layer in the active map"* Are you trying to add graphics to an annotation group which is associated with a layer? When you turn that layer off then the graphic will disappear too so labels in other layers will show. Whilst that layer is visible the graphic would obscure the labels.

I think @Chris W is on the right track, if you want labels to *always* show even if you have drawn graphics on top of them then you need to change the properties of the labels for that particular layer.

Below is a sample of VBA that changes these properties for the first layer in the map. Once it has executed any labels covered by a graphic (I tested it with a polygon) should appear.

```vb
Public Sub test()
    ' Get document
    Dim pMXDocument As IMxDocument
    Set pMXDocument = ThisDocument

    ' Get map
    Dim pMap As IMap
    Set pMap = pMXDocument.FocusMap

    ' Get first layer, assumed this is what you want to label
    Dim pLayer As ILayer
    Set pLayer = pMap.Layer(0)
    Dim pGeoFeatureLayer As IGeoFeatureLayer
    Set pGeoFeatureLayer = pLayer

    ' Ensure labels are visible
    pGeoFeatureLayer.DisplayAnnotation = True

    ' Get Annotation properties collection
    Dim pAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection As IAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection2
    Set pAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection = pGeoFeatureLayer.AnnotationProperties

    ' Get the annotation layer property
    Dim pAnnotateLayerProperties As IAnnotateLayerProperties
    Dim id As Long
    pAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection.QueryItem 0, pAnnotateLayerProperties, id

    ' Ensure all features will be labelled
    pAnnotateLayerProperties.LabelWhichFeatures = esriAllFeatures

    ' Get label engine, do this by QI annotation layer property
    Dim pLabelEngineLayerProperties As ILabelEngineLayerProperties2
    Set pLabelEngineLayerProperties = pAnnotateLayerProperties

    ' Set overposter properties
    Dim pBasicOverposterLayerProperties As IBasicOverposterLayerProperties4
    Set pBasicOverposterLayerProperties = pLabelEngineLayerProperties.BasicOverposterLayerProperties
    pBasicOverposterLayerProperties.GenerateUnplacedLabels = True
    Dim pOverposterLayerProperties As IOverposterLayerProperties2
    Set pOverposterLayerProperties = pLabelEngineLayerProperties.OverposterLayerProperties
    pOverposterLayerProperties.TagUnplaced = False

    ' Refresh display
    pMXDocument.ActiveView.Refresh
End Sub
```